# Making simple, web based map without uploading data to 3rd party websites?

Tags: web-mapping, software-recommendations, arcgis-platform, offline, free-software

I have a lot of point data (Lat, Long) that I want to display on a map. I want the map to be accessible to other users on my network, ideally via a web browser. However, I don't want to (read will not be allowed to) upload this data to ArcGIS online or any similar website.

I would also like to be able to customize the points, have them showing a little pop up window (giving information on each point - number of samples etc) and use clustering (because some points have been studied several times and will have different records at exactly the same coordinates).

I need a free (or very cheap) solution, and I have no programming skills. I've tried the followwing -

ArcGIS Viewer for flex - looked good, but the only way to add local data is via a widget, but then you can't customize the display or add pop ups etc?

ArcGIS Explorer - Again this looked really good, but I couldn't seem to get any control over the pop up information or how the points displayed

ArcGIS for SharePoint - this was the best one, but doesn't seem to be able to do the clustering.

I know I'm asking for quite a lot of free software here, but is there anything that will do it? The ArcGIS API for Silverlight looks like it would do the job, but I'm not sure I'm smart enough to use it. I have access to ArcGIS 10 Desktop, but not ArcGIS Server, is there anything I can export from here? Or have I missed something obvious somewhere?

Comment: I've done something similar with points as GeoJSON, leaflet (http://leafletjs.com) for the web map and its markercluster (https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) plugin to cluster the points. You will have to do some programming though.

Comment: Check out ArcGIS Portal, pretty much like a private ArcGIS Online

Answer (score 1):

Use the plugin [QGIS2leaf](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis2leaf/) for [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org). The plugin exports a portable [leaflet map](http://leafletjs.com/). This is basically a html-file. Your data will be in a separate data-folder, and the necessary libraries, css, etc also saved alongside. You can place the main file (index.html) and the associated files on a file share or on a intranet. The latter depends a bit on how the hosting server.

[image: Folder structure]

Make the map in QGIS by following [this tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html). Not much to it really. Once you have your points on the map pane in QGIS start up the qgis2leaf-plugin which will be available under the **Web**-menu.

The user interface is straightforward. It will allow you to add your data , choose your extent, background maps etc. It also supports clustering of point data, which is what you also indicate is something you need.

[image: qgis2leaf user interface]

Your map will not be anything out of the extrordinary, but with some html-fidling you should be just fine.

[image: sample map]

The only drawback is that the plug-in once in a while does not produce a map export. This does not happen often, so if at first it does not work - try again.